# Typo3 No template was found for new FrontendForms

Tags: forms, typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.x

I'm experimenting a bit with Forms in TYPO 3 version 8.7.13

I have created a form in the typo 3 backend, all good and it looks good, however when I add the form to a page and the load the front page I get the error

```
 Sorry, the requested view was not found.

 The technical reason is: No template was found. View could not be resolved 
 for action "render" in class "TYPO3\CMS\Form\Controller\FormFrontendController".
```

Is there anything that needs to be added to the Typoscript config in order for them to work ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the static template in your TypoScript template.

Comment: its the built in system extension with the CMS 7.7.13, shouldnt it work out the box

Comment: Yes, but as that is an extension you don't use by default, there is a static template you need to include.

Answer (score 1):

You have a TYPO3 form plugin on your page. See the details of the form system extension in the TYPO3 backend page module.

```
**Form No form selected.**
```

Apply the necessary [yaml file](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/8.7/en-us/Concepts/Configuration/Index.html) to your form. Or hide or delete the form plugin.